# UI creation ideas

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Please take a look at www.microsoft.com website. I am also attaching a screenshot here.
The UI is created like the new Windows Phone 7 interface where if you click the arrow on the far right of the screen, the entire display changes with a different div.

I think that this is a great way of using up space to show very large forms or articles.

Can someone suggest how to create this kind of layout?  Can you do this through jQuery?

Pratik[image]

Comment: Is it me or is the microsoft website really slow?

Comment: @gary it's just you :) @Pratik - this is a good place to start : http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jquery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html)

You can use this, you just need to put the next class to the right column, but you can see example for this in this site.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of menu is **called a horizontal accordion**. Searching on Google will yield many results. You can find many examples, one that comes to mind is this: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but I found the [Horinaja](http://www.davidmassiani.com/horinaja/index.php) plugin for jQuery the other day which looks really good.